# Ubuntu doesn't copy video files to Sandisk USB Flash drive

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, video, usb-drive

I recently purchased a new SanDisk Cruzer Glide 32 Gigabyte flash drive. I tried to put movies on the flash drive, and it seems to work, but when I plugged it into the PS3, the video files did not show up at all i.e. nonexistent to PS3. When I plugged it into a Windows 7 computer, instead of "Video Clip," like all of the other videos put on there from the PS3, it said "File," and had a different icon.

In case the thought occurs to someone, there is nothing wrong with the files themselves.

I had another SanDisk flash drive, but it was 16 Gigabyte, and not "Glide." That is what I normally use to transfer video files to and fro the PS3, but it is not in my possession at the time, so I have not been able to test it yet. When I do get it back, I will test it, and if it works, then I know it is SanDisk's fault and not Ubuntu's. But, since I can't test it, I wondered if anyone else has had this problem, has anyway of testing it, etc.

I'm almost sure it is Ubuntu though, I have the same problem with another flash drive that is not SanDisk, or at least I don't think so. Someone gave it to me, and it has PNC on it, which is a bank, so I'm not sure if it could just be a SanDisk flash drive with a PNC outfit.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your files are not named with a suffix. (.avi, .mpg, .mp4, etc)

This produces files that work just fine on Linux because it uses `magic` (not kidding, the pattern match data is literally called magic) to determine file type (use `man magic` at a terminal for a longer explanation).

Windows on the other hand trusts the name of the file to decide what to do with it. The default configuration of Windows hides these file extensions ; most advanced users regard this as an unsafe behaviour (because it's too easy to ship a virus program with an icon that makes it look like a video or image).

I can't say I have experience with a PS3, but it will play these encodings, apparently. I don't know if it needs files named a particular way.

http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/video/filetypes.html

Comment: Okay, I'll rename the files with the proper suffix, all of which are .avi. It actually makes sense too. I usually remove the suffixes after they make it to the PS3, but this time, I downloaded a ton of videos at a place away from home, so, to kill time, I just renamed the files without the suffixes. Should I rename the files that are already on the flash drive, or should I rename them on the computer and transfer them again?

Comment: There should be no difference. Bear in mind that AVI is a container format, and as such the video encodings inside the container may be incompatible with the PS3, and this may be the issue ; you may have to transcode them with something like Handbrake, VLC or mencoder.

Comment: Oh, and I just looked at the files I put onto the flash drive from the PS3. Despite being named without the suffix on the machine itself, the files now have the proper suffix automatically.

And I already knew about avi, encoders, etc. I know if it is not compatible, it will tell me, and I have used Handbrake and Mencoder before/ I didn't know you could transcode with VLC though.

Comment: Victory! Thanks for the help. I usually never touch the suffixes at all, and I think I will return to that. Just in case I need to transfer anything again and forget your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please check to make sure the format is supported on PS3.

Also, you may want to make sure the file transfers have completed. The easiest way, that I know of, is to eject the flash drive and if it says that the drive is busy then it's still copying files.